# Add input value check on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

This is the code I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/21/

```
var container = $('.copies'),
    value_src = $('#current'),
    maxFields = 10,
    currentFields = 1;

$('.copy_form').on('click', '.add', function () {
    if (currentFields < maxFields) {
        var value = value_src.val();
        var html = '<div class="line">' +
            '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
            '</div>';

        $(html).appendTo(container);
        value_src.val('');
        currentFields++;
    } else {
        alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
    }
})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

I want to stop fields being added if there is nothing in the input box when the add button is pressed, so for example I would like to have an alert come up when the user clicks add and there is nothing in the box.

I think it's something like this but I am new to javascript:

```
if { val == null
alert("Nothing to be added");
}
```

Could anyone show me how to implement this check in my current code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($.trim(value) != "") {
      var html = '<div class="line">' +
          '<input class="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
          '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
          '</div>';

      $(html).appendTo(container);
      value_src.val('');
      currentFields++;
}
else{
     alert("no value")
}
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/23/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/22/), based in yours

The added part is:

```
if ($('#current').val().length <= 0) {
    alert("Nothing to be added");
    return;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var value = $.trim(value_src.val());
if(!value){
    alert('empty');
    return;
}
```

Ex:

```
var container = $('.copies'),
    value_src = $('#current'),
    maxFields = 10,
    currentFields = 1;

$('.copy_form').on('click', '.add', function () {
    if (currentFields < maxFields) {
        var value = $.trim(value_src.val());
        if(!value){
            alert('empty');
            return;
        }

        var html = '<div class="line">' +
            '<input class="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
            '</div>';

        $(html).appendTo(container);
        value_src.val('');
        currentFields++;
    } else {
        alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
    }
})
.on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9xaN/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var container = $('.copies'),
    value_src = $('#current'),
    maxFields = 10,
    currentFields = 1;

$('.copy_form').on('click', '.add', function () {
    if (currentFields < maxFields) {
        var value = value_src.val();
        if (value == "") {
            alert("No input");
        }
        else{
        var html = '<div class="line">' +
            '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
            '</div>';

        $(html).appendTo(container);
        value_src.val('');
        currentFields++;
       }
    } else {
        alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
    }
})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your default value is `add`, a simple check will do the trick:

```
if (this.value == "Add" || this.value == "") {
    alert("empty!");
    return false;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/24/

Answer (score 1):

The condition could be:

```
if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
```

This is comparing the value to `''` which is a blank string. It also uses jQuerys `$.trim()` to remove any whitespace from the beginning and end of the value so that if the value only contains whitespace then it won't pass the check.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/27/)

Added to your code, it would look like:

```
if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
    if (currentFields < maxFields) {
        var value = value_src.val();
        var html = '<div class="line">' +
            '<input class="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
            '</div>';

        $(html).appendTo(container);
        value_src.val('');
        currentFields++;
    } else {
        alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
    }
} else {
    alert("You didn't enter anything");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/28/

inside your first if statement check the length of the input with:

```
if($.trim(value) != '')
```

Change your code to this:

```
var container = $('.copies');
    value_src = $('#current');
    maxFields = 10;
    currentFields = 1;

$('.copy_form').on('click', '.add', function () {
    if (currentFields < maxFields) {

        var value = value_src.val();
        if($.trim(value) != ''){
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input class="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
            currentFields++;
        }else{
            alert('Field empty!');
        }
    } else {
        alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
    }
})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```